# Is it feasible to support multiple applications of the same type that are all written in different languages?

Tags: multilingual

As much as we would all like to say it is a benefit to programmers to be language agnostic, is it really feasible to support multiple enterprise Web applications of the same type all written in different languages? Think about how complicated a CMS or e-commerce system can be -- now imagine supporting three different CMS platforms all written in different languages. I would hate to be known as a .NET or Java or PHP shop, but I also don't want to be the vendor who says they can support a solution they have never worked with, upsetting a client who wonders why we can't get something done right on time. Can anyone speak from experience on this? Does your company usually just suck it up, and try and to learn a new platform on the fly? Do you bill up-to-speed, or eat those costs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it all depends on who your clients are and what they expect.  I think knowing about different technologies is good, but really when you're hired by someone, they expect you to know what you are doing.  Personally, I would much rather be known that I do a really good job with a certain type of technology and when hired, I get the job done well.

If you try and go after every contract without regard to what your core competencies are, you aren't going to succeed.  You'll anger the people who do hire you and make mistakes, and you'll potentially miss opportunities where you can really shine.  Sometimes you have to make compromises to pay the bills, but if you aren't careful, it can bite you in the end.

The large consulting firms I've worked with throw resources at it and hope they don't anger too many people.  They mainly do this because they know that the people who work with the consultants and get angry when they don't get the job done aren't the ones making the decisions to keep them hired.  To them (not all of them I know, but some definately), don't care if they screw up because they ultimately know they can convince the VPs and SVPs to keep them around.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I think you tend to see this kind of thing happen over time, no matter how disciplined the organization is. It's natural for new methodologies to come bundled in the form of new libraries, frameworks, or even languages. Keep in mind that a .NET shop may well have been a ASP/VB shop at one time. They'll probably still maintain older systems for clients, because there's little benefit to rewriting everything from scratch.

I'm not sure anyone has the luxury to keep everything "the same," because language issues are minor compared to library or framework issues -- especially the ones you build yourself.